# I am having problems installing underscore with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the NodeJS LTS v14.15.0 installed on my Windows 10. I have npm 5.5.1. I am trying to install Underscore via the command prompt npm i underscore. I keep getting the message "npm does not support Node.js v14.15.0".

I have tried to reinstall NodeJS, expecting to have the newest version of npm installed along with it, but I keep getting 5.5.1. I have tried running npm install -g npm, but keep getting the same error "npm does not support Node.js v14.15.0".  Not sure what else to do. I am new to NodeJS. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall `npm`

```
npm uninstall -g npm
```

and then reinstall NodeJs.

Comment: I still get the same message: npm does not support Node.js v14.15.0

Comment: I had this problem and this solution worked for me.

After doing this, what version do you get now when you do npm -v?
(To be on the safe side, start a new cmd before doing this)